# Magmi - Mass Select/Multiselect Attribute value translater csv format

Tags: magmi

I am trying to use the Mass Select/Multiselect Attribute value translater Utility in Magmi to import attribute options into magento. I'm having issues getting the utility to work correctly and would like to verify that I have the correct CSV format.

The format I have so far is below. I believe my "value" column is incorrect, I have been unable to determine what the column header should me.

```
attribute_code, store:admin, value, position
color,          admin,       red,   0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you even read the Magmi documentation?  This format is entirely incorrect.  Please read the [Import new products](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_new_products) wiki article to get the correct and mandatory import columns.

Comment: @Axel I am not importing products I am importing attributes. And yes I have read the documentation.

Comment: Magmi is based on product importing.  You need to read the documentation and follow it carefully for it to work for your needs.  You cannot simply import or update attributes without tying it to a product.

Comment: @Axel I'm trying to understand how to use the utility class MassOptionAttributeValImporter. under \plugins\utilities\massopt_translate\. Should I not be using this plugin?